# Populating comment field using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

I am new to using Python and seek help building a code for an ArcGIS project. I took one introductory C programming course in school, but other than that I am green.

My objective is to have the conditions below fill a new comment field in the attribute table with the following return statements. Multiple return statements can be true for one attribute.

```
def comments(?): *comments is the field I wish to populate with return statements. 

    if (((PLOT_MASTER.HEIGHT - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OHT" ) >0.1) OR ((PLOT_MASTER.HEIGHT - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OHT" ) <-0.1)): 
        return “Height does not match OHT”

    elif (((PLOT_MASTER.STOCKING_D - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.STKG" ) >0.01) OR ((PLOT_MASTER.STOCKING_D - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.STKG") <-0.01)):
        return "Stocking_D does not match STKG" 

    elif (PLOT_MASTER.LEADING_SPECIES_CODE<> "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OLEADSPC"):
        return "Leading_Species_Code does not match OLEADSPC" 

    elif (PLOT_MASTER.AGE<> "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OAGE"):
        return "Age does not match OAGE"

    else ((( PLOT_MASTER.ECO_CODE - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.PRI_ECO_2" ) >0.01) OR ((PLOT_MASTER.ECO_CODE - "BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.PRI_ECO_2") <-0.01))
        return "ECO_CODE does not match PRI_ECO"
```

comments(?)

Comment: This isn't really a directed question suitable for the site.  When you run your code what happens?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: As a field calculator expression, which I assume this is, the fields are out of scope.. you need to feed them into your calculation as variables  Have a read of http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm . I would suggest starting with an empty string and then concatenate your fail statements then return the fail string; as soon as the interpreter hits a return statement **no other code is evaluated** so if you're expecting even the remote possibility of failing on more than one condition **do not return**. As an aside I think you should abs(value)

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the code I can see a few glaring errors:

- Not equals is `!=` not `<>`. The `<>` operator is VB, in C and python not equals is `!=`
- You've copied some code that has been in Microsoft Word or Outlook at some stage... These text editors are very helpful, too helpful in fact, it's replaced your `""` string with `“”` which isn't python string identifiers.

I covered in my comments the multiple return statements which will drop out your code as soon as a condition returns true.. to check for multiple conditions you can build a string or a list of strings then join together:

```
def comments(PLOT_MASTER_HEIGHT,
                         BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OHT,
                         PLOT_MASTER_STOCKING_D,
                         BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_STKG,
                         PLOT_MASTER_LEADING_SPECIES_CODE,
                         BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OLEADSPC,
                         PLOT_MASTER_AGE,
                         BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OAGE,
                         PLOT_MASTER_ECO_CODE,
                         BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_PRI_ECO_2)

    failStrings = [] # a new empty list
    if abs(PLOT_MASTER_HEIGHT - BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OHT) > 0.1:
        failStrings.append('Height does not match OHT')

    if abs(PLOT_MASTER_STOCKING_D - BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_STKG ) >0.01:
        failStrings.append('Stocking_D does not match STKG')

    if PLOT_MASTER_LEADING_SPECIES_CODE != BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OLEADSPC:
        failStrings.append('Leading_Species_Code does not match OLEADSPC')

    if PLOT_MASTER_AGE != BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_OAGE:
        failStrings.append('Age does not match OAGE')

    if abs( PLOT_MASTER_ECO_CODE - BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin_PRI_ECO_2 ) >0.01:
        failStrings.append('ECO_CODE does not match PRI_ECO')

    return ','.join(failStrings) # joins the list strings together with a comma
```

Instead of checking if `> 0.1` or `< -0.1` I have used the `abs()` operator so you only need to check greater than because the value is not negative.

In field calculator you would call like this:

```
comments(!PLOT_MASTER.HEIGHT!, !BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OHT!,!PLOT_MASTER.STOCKING_D!, !BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.STKG!,!PLOT_MASTER.LEADING_SPECIES_CODE!, !BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OLEADSPC!,!PLOT_MASTER.AGE!, !BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.OAGE!,!PLOT_MASTER.ECO_CODE!, !BL_FinalLayer_SpatialJoin.PRI_ECO_2!)
```

[image]